# Only three records in SQLite database at a time

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android application in which i need to keep a record of three most recent actions performed by user on a screen. These records are stored in SQLite database.

I want to implement a specific feature such that whenever a fourth action is performed, the least recent record automatically gets replaced with the new one.

I searched for a few ways to limit the number of rows. One of them was to use Triggers in database and I am not very familiar with the use of triggers.

Please help me implement the functionality.

Comment: For only 3 values, use SharedPreferences with a simple FIFO buffer.

Comment: @Simon please check my comment at Jim's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your comment, i understand that 3 is just arbitrary number you said.. so you have a large database and you want to restrict the number or rows with a specific limit

use below trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg1 AFTER INSERT ON table1
WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM table1) > 3
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM table1 WHERE _id = (SELECT min(_id) FROM table1 );
END;
```

assuming that _id is identity column, it should work.

If you dont want to use _id, use a datetime field for identifying oldest log assuming that not more than 1 log is entered within same millisecond fraction 
(better use min(_id) as it is autogenerated increamental primary key)

Answer (score 0):

Database triggers are useful when you need to offload system processing to the database "server" (or if you have complex database constraints that several systems may access and not do so with proper enforcement of constraints). You don't really need it here. Just Delete/Insert (all rows or delete the least recent and then insert the most recent). You won't have performance issues.

And unless you have a business requirement to store this in a database, it seems more like SharedPreferences would work fine.

Comment: there is a lot of data related to a particular action that needs to be stored. So sharedpreferences probably can't handle that much stuff and also the data has to be stored in a database.

Comment: databases are generally used to store long-term data, not transient data like this. My answer should still address your issue - triggers would work, but are not at all necessary. Neither are any other database level actions (stored procedures, index constraints, etc.), based on your description of the problem.

Comment: so can you please help me with some algorithm or just guide me how should i achieve this?